# How can I change company specific job and get into skilled job?

Tags: job-search, career-development, india, skills, transition

I completed my Masters of Computer Applications in 2014. I got selected into manufacturing multinational corporation ( Non-IT) with good salary (3.12 Lakhs, 312,000 rupees, per year) from college campus among 300 students. They told us that I will be working on Oracle JD Edwards (ERP) and other projects as and when required. I have been working with same company till now. My current cost to the company is 10 LPA (one million rupees per year).
what I did from 2014 to 2019.

**1st Year**: end user support and call management, like solving software, PC, Projector related issues.

**2nd Year** :  1st year work plus ERP Development, ERP work was very less, also did networking projects, IT related procurements,Renewing AMCs, managing UPS ,Server room management,
many hours were passed in end user support only.

**3rd Year**: end user support and above mentioned work.

**4th Year**: got chance to learn SharePoint as required along with the above mentioned works

**5th Year**: some sharepoint development as I was a beginner. Mobile distribution in company , end user support and all other work mentioned above.

Now I am not able to get similar job as my experience is specific to this company
I feel my carrier is ruined. I have same people working in my department for 7 years and 9 years with no specific skills.

I started learning the SharePoint more and more but my experience and cost to the company does not match for IT companies.

What should I do now for switching.
As I see respect issue and job security concerns.

Comment: We need a glossary for this one. CTC = “cost to company,” salary + benefits. LPA = lakhs (100,000 rupees) per annum. MCA = “master of computer applications,” a 3-year IT degree in India. MNC = “multinational corporation” ERP  = “enterprise resource planning” (most people probably know the last two.)  UPS is probably uninterruptible power supplies; AMC, I can’t figure that one out.

Comment: AMC is for Annual Maintenance Contract

Comment: "Now I am not able to get similar job" how many job applications have you filed? How many interviews did you have?

Comment: around 40 applications..shorlisted in 10....not interviwed in 6 as salary even same salary was high for them...not able to crack 4 interviews...working on lacking...

Answer (score 3):

First of all your career is never ruined, but it might take an extra step to reach the position you want to. If that is an IT company, make sure you know exactly what you want to do in an 'IT Company' and start doing projects in that direction.

What I have seen with other people in similar positions is switching to consultancy, contract work or temporary work. This is a great way to see different companies and broaden your skills. They got the experience they needed to close the gap between their current skills and experience and what was required for the job they wanted. After some years they successfully applied for the position they wanted.

Second:

> I started learning the SharePoint more and more but my experience and CTC does not match for IT companies.

Ask (and answer) questions likes this to yourself:

- What do you want to do at an IT-company?
- And where is the gap with your current experience?
- Where could you get that experience?

Comment: +1 for the questions at the bottom. I also had a very company-specific position for quite some time (3 years) and another piece of advice I offer is: understand which skills and capabilities you developed in this position and use more "marketeable" terms for them. You'd be surprised with how much you learn in a company-specific position.

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> What should I do now for switching

First, you need to decide: What do you want to switch *to?* What is your dream job? What kind of work do you want to do, and for what kind of company?

Many people who complain, *my career is ruined! I don't have the skills to get a job!* are really just either not looking for the right next job, or they're not giving themselves credit for the skills they have. Being skilled at configuring or developing for ERP software is an incredibly valuable skill - it may be a niche job, but it can be wildly profitable. However, if you're trying to get a job doing something totally unrelated to that, you may feel like you're failing.

So:

- Identify your dream job. Determine what skills it requires.
- Evaluate your current job, and what skills you have.
- Look for a job that can be used as a stepping stone - something where your current skills are relevant, but the job also overlaps with what you *really* want to be doing.
- **go get that job.**
- Repeat the above steps until you're in your dream job.

Speaking from personal experience, I started out in a job somewhat similar to what you're describing, working on configuration and development for ERPs and other enterprise software. I'm now doing something very, very different where those skills really don't directly apply. I didn't make that change overnight, in one single jump - if I had applied for my current role right out of that first role, I would have been quickly turned down. So, realize that this might be a longer path than you'd like - but, that doesn't have to mean it's impossible. **Come up with a goal, make a plan, and take steps towards your goal.**